# Sum of the sets in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. Define 
$$ A + B  =\{ a + b | a \in A , b \in B \}$$

Consider the sets 
$$ W = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x > 0 , y >0 \} $$

$$ X = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x \in \mathbb R , y = 0 \}$$

$$ Y = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | xy =1  \}$$

$$Z = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | |x| \leq 1, |y| \leq 1 \}$$

Which of the following statements are true

a.  $W + X $ is open.

b. $X + Y$ is closed.

c. $Y + Z$ is closed.

a. I know that $W$ is the first quaddrant  excludinng the $x - axis$ and $y - axis$ in the x-y plane and $X$ is the x - axis. Take $(-n ,0) + (x,y) $ where $ n \in \mathbb N $ and $ 0 <x < 1 ,  0< y < 1$, which is not the interior point of $W +X$ , So it is not open.

I do not know how to check the option (b) and (c) whether they aree closed not. Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution to part a is not correct.

We can write the sum of sets as a union:

$$A+B = \bigcup_{b\in B}(A+b)$$
where $A+b=\{a+b|a\in A\}$ is the set $A$ translated in the plane. So the sum is a union of translations of either set. You can use this to work out what each of the given sums looks like, and from that work out if they are open or closed.

For the $W+X$ case you don't even need to work out what it looks like. As $W$ is open, any translation of it is. Thus $W+X$ being the union of open sets is open.

For part b, take $(x,y)=(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)\in X+Y$, where $(x_1,y_1)\in X$ and $(x_2,y_2)\in Y$. Then we know that $y_1=0$ and as $1=x_2y_2$, $y_2\not=0$. Thus $y=y_1+y_2=y_2\not=0$. As $x_1$ has free rein over $\mathbb R$, $x$ does also. Thus $X+Y=\mathbb R^2\setminus X$. That is, it is the plane without the $x$ axis. This is fairly clearly not closed; any point on the $x$ axis is a limit point not in the set.

Try to employ a similar method to work out what the set $Y+Z$ looks like, and from that decide if it's open or closed. If you need more help, I can give more hints.

Answer (score 2):

$W+X$ is the open upper half plane, thus open.  Given $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, with $y >0$, then $(x,y)=(|x|+1,y)+(x-|x|-1,0)\in W+X$.

$X+Y$ is the real plane minus the X-axis, thus not closed. Given any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $y\neq 0$, let $x'=1/y$, so that $(x',y) \in Y$. Then $(x-x',0)\in X$ and so $(x,y)=(x-x',0)+(x',y)$ $\in X+Y$.  Conversely, if we have $(x_1,0)\in X$ and $(x_2,y)\in Y$, then $y\neq 0$ because $x_2y=1$.

$X+Z$ is the strip $\{(x,y):|y|\le 1\}$, closed. Indeed, given any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $|y|\leq 1$, we have $(x,y)=(x,0)+(0,y)\in X+Z$.

Comment: The question asks for $Y+Z$, not $X+Z$.

Comment: Compact + closed = closed. So (c) is closed with X or with Y.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me your valuable time

Comment: Apologies for my confusion.  Error is difficult to avoid.  I will try to be more careful if I make further answers.